# error: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

Tags: python, oracle, plone, buildout, cx-oracle

I'm working on Plone.

**PRELUDE**

I've installed:

oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

and also cx_Oracle.
I've tested the installations and it's all ok: db connection successfully.

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
echo $TNS_ADMIN
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/admin
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I've edited buildout.cfg as follows:

```
[...]
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
    collective.documentviewer
    Products.OpenXml
    Products.AROfficeTransforms
    tus
    wildcard.foldercontents==2.0a7
    **cx_Oracle**
[...]
```

I receive this error:

```
Unused options for buildout: 'environment-vars'.
Installing instance.
Getting distribution for 'cx-Oracle'.
error: cannot locate an Oracle software installation
An error occurred when trying to install cx-Oracle 5.1.3. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'cx-Oracle'.
Error: Couldn't install: cx-Oracle 5.1.3
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

"cannot locate an Oracle software installation" How to fix this?

Comment: did you added ORACLE_HOME/bin to PATH as well as libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the same problem, background is:

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
```

But:
    sudo env | grep ORACLE_HOME

yields nothing.

The solution:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add the line :

```
Defaults env_keep += "ORACLE_HOME"
```

As found [here](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2014/08/25/getting-python-to-play-with-oracle-using-cxoracle-on-mint-and-ubuntu.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that the right envvars are setted for the user that run the Plone instance.

The best way is to add those vars in the buildout configuration::

```
[buildout]
...

[instance]
...

environment-vars =
    ...
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64/lib
    ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64
```

(This is what I have on a CentOS installation)